# WSO2 ESB - transform a HTTP 202 accepted response

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

The Endpoint_BPS_CreateCaseService/UpdateCaseService endpoints below both point to one-way BPEL services running on WSO2 BPS. WSO2 BPS returns a HTTP 202 accepted message instantly when they are invoked.

The client application that I am using will throw a fault if it does not get a valid SOAP envelope as a response so I'm going to use a proxy service in ESB to wrap around the BPEL process.

How do I use a WSO2 ESB proxy service to forward a SOAP envelope to Endpoint_BPS_* below and then return a SOAP envelope response to my client app?

I also want to execute the faultSequence "ProcessFault" if either endpoint is unavailable or times out. I previously used the OUT_ONLY to get around the response issue above but it means I can't detect endpoint problems. Unless it is possible to do both somehow?

Another thing I've tried is cloning the message but this was a bit messy.

Any help greatly appreciated

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="BPSProxyService" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target faultSequence="ProcessFault">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="MESSAGE" value="BEGIN BPSProxyService" />
         </log>
         <switch source="//*[local-name()='Operation']">
            <case regex="create">
               <send>
                  <endpoint key="Endpoint_BPS_CreateCaseService" />
               </send>
            </case>
            <case regex="update">
               <send>
                  <endpoint key="Endpoint_BPS_UpdateCaseService" />
               </send>
            </case>
         </switch>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2" />
         <class name="esb.mediators.InjectSOAPEnvelope" />
         <log level="full">
            <property name="MESSAGE" value="END BPSProxyService" />
         </log>
         <send />
         <drop />
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL key="common/bpsproxyservice/bpsproxyservice.wsdl">
      <resource location="schema.xsd" key="common/schema_v2.xsd" />
   </publishWSDL>
</proxy>
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work also. <property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2" />
<class name="esb.mediators.InjectSOAPEnvelope" />

Answer (score 7):

When you receive a 'HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted' response from your backend like BPS in the outSequence of your Proxy Service, then you need the `<property name="SC_ACCEPTED" value="false" scope="axis2"/>` statement to modify the '202'-response into something else.

Example:

    `<property name="SC_ACCEPTED" value="false" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <response>
                <result>OK</result>
            </response>
        </format>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>
    <send/>`

The response is transformed into 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' with a response message.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" parameter with the "OUT_ONLY" in the inSequence of the proxy service as follows.

```
<property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

For more information use the following article:
http://mohanadarshan.wordpress.com/2013/05/05/out_only-scenario-in-proxy-service-wso2-esb/